# Declaration of Function before defining causing error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, function-declaration

I have been trying to write a code that can check if there is the sequence of 123 in an array or not for which I made a **check** function which does that work. But declaring this function before **main** function is causing problems with compiling when I am writting the arguments in it.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int check(int, int);      /* This line is cauing trouble */

void main()
{   int arr_size;
    int a[]={0,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
    arr_size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("%d",check(a, arr_size));

}

int check(int a[], int arr_size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<arr_size-1; i++)
    {
    if(a[i]==1 && a[i+1]==2 && a[i+2]==3)
        {
            return 1;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The screenshot of the error is attached along. [image: Error produced in CodeBlocks]

Declaration part is not causing any problem and the code is working fine when I am not writting any argument in it as shown below.

```
int check();
```

I expected that while declaring function it should take the prarameters which is not the case here. Guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare `int check(int, int)` to `int check(int[], int)` bellow. Copy paste error?

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but `i<arr_size-1` should be `i < arr_size - 2` so that `a[i + 2]` will not access memory beyond the array in the last iteration of the loop

Comment: I'm surprised that `conio.h` compiles fine in GCC for you

Comment: @Spikatrix **arr_size**  in this case is **13** and array starts at **0** so **arr_size-1 = 12** which means **i<12** thus i can taket the maximum value of **11**

Comment: @amangoyal `i<12` right. In the last iteration, `i` is 11. So the `if` condition would be `if(a[11]==1 && a[12]==2 && a[13]==3)` and `a[13]` is invalid since the array starts at 0

Comment: `main` should [return `int`, not `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: @StoryTeller I changed the **int check(int, int)** to **int check(int[ ],int)** and now its working. I didnt know that we have to pass braces in the declaraion part. Thanks. Also off the topic, how to place code in grey box? I am unable to do it.

Comment: @Spikatrix I understand your point and I dont understand why its showing correct output with **i<arr_size-1**. I have tried the new array **int a[]={1,2,3,0,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,1,2,3};** with **123**  at the end but still its working.

Comment: @amangoyal In C, just because something works doesn't mean it is absolutely correct. It may have worked for you with the wrong code now, but later on when you do it with other inputs, you might see incorrect outputs. Basically, in C, when you do something invalid, you invoke something called Undefined Behavior. It means that _anything_ could be the result.

Comment: @amangoyal Surround code with backticks \` to make them appear in a grey box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a conflict there.

`int` and `int *` (or, `int []`) are not the same types.

Update your forward declaration to be

```
int check(int *, int);
```

That said, given the usage of `arr_size`, you need to change the loop condition from

```
for(i=0;i<arr_size-1; i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<arr_size-2; i++)
```

since you're using `[i+2]` as one of the index inside the loop.

---

Regarding the reason for `int *` (a pointer) to be equivalent to an array in this case, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.3

> A declaration of a parameter as *‘‘array of type’’* shall be adjusted to *‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’*, [...]

Comment: **int***    because it is an array?

Comment: @amangoyal when you pass an array you pass the starting address of that array that's why you need a pointer to store that address.